# Не работает CDN из документации vue js 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Даже элементарные скрипты vue не работают:

```html
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id='app'>
        {{ lastName }}, {{ firstName }}
    </div>
    
  
    <script>
        const App = Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    firstName: 'Christopher',
                    lastName: 'Harrison'
                };
            }
        });
        // Registering and mounting our app
        App.mount('#app');
    </script>
```

P.S. В английской документации CDN указан по другому и с ним всё работает:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
        {{ lastName }}, {{ firstName }}
    </div>
       
    <script>
        const App = Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    firstName: 'Christopher',
                    lastName: 'Harrison'
                };
            }
        });
        // Registering and mounting our app
        App.mount('#app');
    </script>
```

Comment: По каким причинам Вам нельзя воспользоваться рабочим вариантом?

Comment: Ответ от сервера https://unpkg.com/ - "Cannot find package vue@next"